# Перегрузка метода с дополнением кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть ли какой-то способ (без прямого копирования кода родительского метода), вызова родительской функции, причем так, чтобы можно было изменять ее состояние, грубо говоря есть такой код:

```
class father():
    def method(self):
        a = 5

class son(father):
    def method(self):
        #something
        a = a ** 2 + 1
        print(a) # 26
```

Comment: `super().method()`?

Comment: Так он же не даст изменить состояние.

Comment: То есть Вы хотите влиять на _локальные_ переменные функции?

Comment: Да, я же написал это в вопросе, что я хочу изменить состояние родительского метода. Даже из примера это понятно.

Comment: нет, так нельзя

Comment: Зачем такое может понадобиться?

Comment: @Эникейщик хочу написать программу, которая пишет программу, такое поведение было бы удобно для меня.

Comment: Можно было бы получить исходный код родительского метода, разбить его на стейтменты и выполнить через exec(Это даже сработает во втором Пайтоне). Однако, в python3 exec не может модифицировать локальные переменные из-за runtime оптимизации)

Comment: Да, я пытался так сделать, поэтому вопрос и возник...